# Visual Studio Mac 2019 - Xamarin.Forms wont connexct to the debugger

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that wont connect to the debugger on iOS 13.3.1 and 13.4.

Specs:

Visual Studio 8.5.3 (build 16)
Xamarin.iOS 13.16
iOS (physical device): 13.4

My project builds, deploys, installs and then appears on my physical device (does not open).
Meanwhile Visual Studio is showing "Waiting to connect to debugger...."  and eventually times out with "Could not connect to debugger" message.

Here is the error message from the stack trace:

error HE0032: Could not mount developer tools on 'iOS Automation': Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: array

Error message seems straight forward, but I am not sure how to handle it.

Can anyone please let me know?

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

Also, I have tried multiple times to Clean the solution

Close it

delete the bin and obj directories from each project

Reopen the solution.

Build each project individually - NOT rebuild solution

After all the projects are built... Then Rebuild Solution

Comment: are you running the latest XCode?  Be sure you actually run XCoode after you install/update, because it may prompt to install some additional tools

Comment: Is this happen even in a new project? Update your XCode to the latest version.